# Force HTML -page reload from server application

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi

I have python based CGI application on my server. It reads json file and generates an HTML page for the browser. But if json file is updated the HTML page should be reloaded.

Can any external code on the server somehow force HTML page reload? So that is open in the user's browser.

Any ideas on how to solve this? It feels stupid code like "reload this HTML every X seconds". What other opportunities do I have?

Comment: Your html can have javascript embedded in it using script tags that can do an AJAX request to the server to check for updates. Your server can either provide the updated JSON in the response or have the response be an instruction to the client side JS to reload the page or not.

Comment: You should probably have a look to websockets.